# Firestore security rules - trouble with permission to write to a collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've attempted to set up a security rule where a person writing a document to a particular collection may only do so if their uid matches the uid contained in the document, but can't get it to work.  In this case I am writing a document to a collection called 'embedUsers' and the document being written contains a uid field that was acquired when the user account was created.

The rules are set up as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
    match /embedUsers/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

The document is written by an Angular client, using the following code:

```
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserModel> = this.afs.doc(`embedUsers/${user.accountAddress}`);
console.log("current logged in user", this.fireUser.uid);
try {
  console.log(user.uid);
  await userRef.set(user, { merge: true });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(`FireAuthService.updateUserData unexpected failure with error ${e.message}`)
  throw new Error("updateUserData failed");
}
console.log("wrote embed user successfully")
```

Although I have checked that the uid of the signed in user matches the uid field in the data object being written, this call to `userRef.set` fails with `FireAuthService.updateUserData unexpected failure with error Missing or insufficient permissions.`  It seems like something must be wrong with my rules but I'm not sure what (if I change the rule to simply say `allow write: if true;` the document gets written as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation), "When writing data ... the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document". So you should adapt your rule to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
    match /embedUsers/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```